# How to set rotation for Baidu map annotation for iOS?

Tags: ios, baidu, baidu-map

I have done everything using Baidu maps SDK for iOS. But I stuck at setting the course for one of the marker. I don't see any property for annotation to set rotation, where I can see for `BMKMaPView`.

Comment: Me also facing same lag, if find solution post here :-)